# extracting data from text file in ssis having all columns in one row without any delemiter

Tags: ssis

How will I extract data having address and name of customer in one row without having any specific delimiter in the file .All rows contain customer name and address information only.how will I put this data into 2 different tables in SSIS

Comment: Are you able to provider an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: I am not sure..This was a question which was asked to me in an interview..with this info only.

Comment: if the values are not separated by a delimiter you would have to make some assumptions. For example, if all names are made up of Firstname and Surname you could use charindex & substring to extract the first two words if they appear before the address.